# Deploying Rails 6 app, with Apache2 and Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

This would be on an AWS server. I have not been able to find a single guide that will walk me through this.

One of these guides was promising, up until the point where I was asked to do:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/puma/puma/master/tools/jungle/init.d/puma
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/puma/puma/master/tools/jungle/init.d/run-puma
```

But neither of these repos seem to exist. I realize this is not a programming question, but I am trying to switch from Passenger, to what Rails is supposed to be using natively, but I can't really find much information about deploying to a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Well
6 month ago the good person answered as a comment on [Rails Server with Apache + Puma (via reverse proxy)](https://learnwithdaniel.com/2015/01/apache-puma-via-reverse-proxy/)

*I'm sure that you have solved the problem already, but for anyone else coming here in the future, using init.d has been deprecated in favour of systemd (starting with version 5 of puma).*

*The init scripts that you mentioned are still available. Go to the project on GitHub, and select the most recent 4.x branch. Under tools, you will find the last release of the files.*